# How to clean my print result on Python with a variable coming from an Excel cell?

Tags: python, excel, text, printing

I am printing on python variables that come from an excel cell.

For example:

On the worksheet.cell(5 , 3) there is the text "YES".

```
condition = worksheet.cell(5 , 3)
print(condition)
```

The problem is that it prints:

```
text:'YES'
```

Instead of just:

```
YES
```

Could you kindly assist?
Thanks.

Comment: What are you using to read the excel file? Is it just the CSV module?

Comment: You could `print(type(condition))` or `help(condition)` to discover by yourself what kind of object this is, and how to extract its text part (though it is probably something along the line of `condition.text`, depending on which module you use to open the sheet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is doable with openpyxl and `.value`:

```
import openpyxl

wbName = 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\wb.xlsx'
wbk = openpyxl.load_workbook(wbName)
for wks in wbk.worksheets:
    condition = wks.cell(1 , 1).value
    print(condition)

wbk.save(wbName)
wbk.close
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the value at a cell with the `value` attribute of the cell object.

```
condition = worksheet.cell(5, 3).value # "YES"
```

The object returned by `.cell()` contains type info as well.